# Launch an app when a user taps a link in an android webview

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, android-app-indexing

I've been looking around for for this but I cannot figure it out. I have

Java file:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url ));
startActivity(browserIntent);
return true;
```

where `url = "facebook.com"`

Or in the manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
         android:host="facebook.com"
        android:scheme="http" />
     <data
         android:host="www.facebook.com"
         android:scheme="http" />
</intent-filter>
```

Basically if the user has an app for a domain it should launch it. It's not a general way, the domains are hardcoded of corse.

Comment: That is called **deep linking** which allows a link to open the app if it's installed. Refer to this doc to enable deep linking in your app https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

[**Android Intents with Chrome**](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents).

Comment: I'm looking for code to be added to `shoudlOverrideLoading`